# Android Location Manager Issue returns same value everytime

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have tried following these two tutorials but every time it requests a GPS location it returns the same location.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

http://techlovejump.com/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

The location always returned is Latitude: 32.89604077 Longitude: -117.20146694

I am not sure why and have spent many hours trying to figure it out. I have been testing on a device as well.

Comment: As I saw, both tutorials are showing your current location. Does it show the same result even if you go to a different place?

Comment: From the links provided, you are emulating a device. If this is true, change the value within the emulator. If you are using a real device, then check if you are not receiving the Location from your ISP provider, other than the Device GPS unit. (to easy check those, open a browser on a desktop and turn on Location in google maps. If its the ISP, the Location will be equal)

Comment: You have to post your code as well to show what you are doing in your application.

Comment: It shows the same result no matter where I am.

Comment: Bonatti I tried what you said and the locations seem to be equal